# Remove elements from XML

Tags: xml, transform

I have XML in the following format:

```
<policy_groups>
    <policy_group>
    <policygroup_name>Application Server with IIS</policygroup_name>
        <policygroup_id>38</policygroup_id>
        <policygroup_description />
        <policygroup_creatorname>VMW2K3-SSI10-KF\VMW2K3-SSI10-KF\Administrator</policygroup_creatorname>
        <policygroup_patchgroup>-1</policygroup_patchgroup>
        <policygroup_signaturegroup>-1</policygroup_signaturegroup>
        <policygroup_system>false</policygroup_system>
        <policygroup_item>
            <policygroupitem_id>83217</policygroupitem_id>
            <policygroupitem_name>.NET Framework Support Service Status</policygroupitem_name>
            <policygroupitem_type>0</policygroupitem_type>
            <policygroupitem_policygroupid>38</policygroupitem_policygroupid>
            <policygroupitem_productname>Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition</policygroupitem_productname>
            <policygroupitem_spname>Gold</policygroupitem_spname>
            <policygroupitem_checkshavlikid>207</policygroupitem_checkshavlikid>
            <policygroupitem_value>Disabled-Not Found</policygroupitem_value>
            <policygroupitem_operator>=</policygroupitem_operator>
            <policygroupitem_displayvalue>Not Installed</policygroupitem_displayvalue>
        </policygroup_item>
        <policygroup_item>
            <policygroupitem_id>85541</policygroupitem_id>
            <policygroupitem_name>.NET Framework Support Service Status</policygroupitem_name>
            <policygroupitem_type>0</policygroupitem_type>
            <policygroupitem_policygroupid>38</policygroupitem_policygroupid>
            <policygroupitem_productname>Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition</policygroupitem_productname>
            <policygroupitem_spname>SP1</policygroupitem_spname>
            <policygroupitem_checkshavlikid>207</policygroupitem_checkshavlikid>
            <policygroupitem_value>Disabled-Not Found</policygroupitem_value>
            <policygroupitem_operator>=</policygroupitem_operator>
            <policygroupitem_displayvalue>Not Installed</policygroupitem_displayvalue>
        </policygroup_item>
    </policy_group>
    </policy_groups>
```

Except there are thousands of `<policygroup_item>`'s in the XML document.

I need to remove any `policygroup_item` where `<policygroupitem_productname>` and `<policygroupitem_spname>` don't match any of the following combinations:

- Windows 2000 Advanced Server SP4
- Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2
- Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition (x64) SP2
- Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition SP2
- Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition (x64) SP2
- Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition SP2
- Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition (x64) SP2
- Windows 2008 Standard Edition SP2
- Windows 2008 R2 Standard (x64) Gold
- Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise (x64) Gold

Is there some way to do this with XSLT or powershell? Or maybe VB script?

Thanks

Brad

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as removing the ones that don't match, think of it as copying the ones that do match. Use the [`<xsl:copy-of>` element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp) on a selection of all the tags you want to keep.

Comment: Don - Thanks for the suggestion although I must admit I've very little experience with xsl. I've tried to google xsl:copy-of but I am not sure how to use it to extract the elements I want. Do you (or anyone else) have any examples that I could use to get started? Thanks

Comment: The link I included in the answer takes you to w3schools.com. It's the best basic introduction to XSLT that I've found on the web. Also check out the XPath reference on the same site. If that doesn't help, I recommend Michael Kay's XSLT book: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0764569090.html